# Deploying Java SE server application in production

Tags: java, deployment, java-server

I have a Java SE server application. It's built using **Netty**. I want to deploy it on our production server with Ubuntu.
For now I use Ubuntu service script that provides some stuff such as `start`, `stop`, `restart` and `status` commands for service, log files managing and actually runs the jar:

```
java -jar server-with-dependencies.jar --args
```

I want to know what is a best practice of deploying and running Java apps with embedded server.

Should I use the same script for production and just copy it by hands to server's `/etc/init.d/` dir? Or maybe create a `.deb` package for my app? And is it OK to run Java SE server app as a linux service?

Thanks.